# wp_mail() is not working for me in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my template code and it is not sending mails to customers in wordpress. please anyone help me to make right this code. thanks

```
<?php
/*
Template name: contact
*/
get_header(); 
$email="test@gmail.com";
$subject="testing";
$message = "hi this is test";
$headers = 'From:' . "testing@gmail.com";

if(wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
echo "sending mail test";
}
else
{
     echo "not";
}

get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the php log file?
[How to find log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked the script and it working. Maybe you have problams on server.

Comment: thanks brother yes it is server problem

Comment: you are welcome =)

Comment: Anything additional to add?

Answer (score 3):

Try to set header

```
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'From:' . "testing@gmail.com";
```

or

It can be problem with your server (hosting)

Comment: Adding `From` fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you are not using php's standard mail function. This plugin will help you. [WP mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

Select "Use PHP mail function to send the emails" from options on settings page and check the emails.